# small image link as a button at the bottom right of the image it is selling

Tags: html, css

Im trying to put a link button to amazon on a picture but not only is it not working its making my website all wonky

```css
.review-page-lander > img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1169px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img.buy-from-button{
  height: 35px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 35px;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="lander-image">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="buy-from-button" src="http://oathtohealth.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Amazon.png" alt="buy at amazon">
  </a>
  <img src="amazon-item.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: What is 'wonky', what is 'not working'??? Does the link open correctly?
 does the image now appeared styled differently? Have you used F12 (web inspect or similar name in whatever browser you are using) to inspect the css rules being applied? 

Most likely just some <a> style rules being inherited, but you HAVE to ask better questions for us to help you, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You could try adding `float: left` and `margin-left: -150px` on the second image to have it 'on top' of the Amazon image. Considering your image link is relative, it's impossible to see your problem. Please update your question so that it shows **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: You have used  `.review-page-lander` in css and `lander-image` as class name in html

Comment: Please update this thread, either accepting an answer or providing detail via comment or edit or even self answer why it doesnt answer your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in my comment, difficult to answer without more info

First off, using `.review-page-lander > img` wont work as the `>` means immediate child, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

To find what else not working, use F12+inspect in chrome (or similar in other browsers) to find what css being applied

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep your product image above your buy button and make buy button float right relatively with `bottom: 40px;`

```css
.lander-image>img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1169px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img.buy-from-button {
  height: 35px;
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lander-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="buy-from-button" src="http://oathtohealth.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Amazon.png" alt="buy at amazon">
  </a>
</div>
```